# Tkinter overlaying text

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning Tkinter and I'm a bit confused.
The code below is showing the white text from the `face_recogniton()` function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from facerec_on_raspberry_pi import face_function #face_function() return recognized person name

root = tk.Tk()

#Fullscreen
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.overrideredirect(False)
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
root.configure(background='black')

def my_mainloop():
    print (face_function())
    instructions = tk.Label(root, text=str(face_function()), font=('Raleway', 55), fg='white', bg='black')
    instructions.place(x=160, y=60)
    root.after(1, my_mainloop)

root.after(1, my_mainloop)

root.mainloop()
```

But the text is overlaying. How can I clean it before showing new text?

Here are the images of what's happening:
[image]

Here is Unknown Person and Barack Obama overlaying -
[image: Barack Obama]

Here is None and Unknown Person overlaying.
[image: None]

Comment: Do you really need to overlay multiple labels? Why not just reuse the same label? You can create a label outside of function and then do label['text'] = 'new text'. Tell me if it's suitable, I'll post full answer.

Comment: Yes, that will work for me, I don't need multiple labels. Can you post a full answer, please? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to re-create your label every time you need to change text. The text of existing label can be changed after creation. Also note the two lines I commented: you don't need both.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from facerec_on_raspberry_pi import face_function #face_function() return recognized person name

root = tk.Tk()

#Fullscreen
root.overrideredirect(True) # Use only one of this two lines: 
root.overrideredirect(False) # you just set a flag and then change it
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
root.configure(background='black')

instructions = tk.Label(root, text='', font=('Raleway', 55), fg='white', bg='black')
instructions.place(x=160, y=60)

def my_mainloop():
    print (face_function())
    instructions['text'] = str(face_function())    
    root.after(1, my_mainloop)

root.after(1, my_mainloop)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Awesome, this is working. Thanks a lot :)